# dropdown list bind from xml file

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am having an issue binding a dropdown from data within an xml file. the xml file looks like so;

```
<agricultural>
<file>
  <text>Acreage_Cotton_Planted</text>
  <value>ACRECOTP Index</value>
</file>
<file>
  <text>Acreage_Corn_Planted</text>
  <value>ACRECRNP Index</value>
</file>
<file>
  <text>Acreage_Soybean_Planted</text>
  <value>ACRESOYP Index</value>
</file>
<file>
  <text>Acreage_Wheat_Planted</text>
  <value>ACREWHTP Index</value>
</file>
</agricultural>
```

I am using this code to return the list from the xml

```
Public Shared Function GetAgDataList(nodestring As String) As List(Of ListItem)
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    'Load XML from the file into XmlDocument object
    doc.Load("~\DataFiles\dataXML.xml") 'this needs to be changed to the server path
    Dim root As XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement
    'Select all nodes with the tag paramter indicated by the nodestring variable
    Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes(nodestring)
    Return (From node As XmlNode In nodeList Let text = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("text").Value.ToString() Let val = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("value").Value.ToString() Select New ListItem(text, val)).ToList()
End Function
```

Isn't the dropdown list control only supposed to display the text? Because my dropdown is showing the text and value concatenated together. For example, Acreage_Corn_PlantedACRECRNP Index. I only want the text, Acreage_Corn_Planted, displayed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code:
I used LINQ to Entity an it works for ASP.NET 3.5 or above:

```
    using System.Xml.Linq;
public class Item {
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyPage : Page { 
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("MyXmlFile.xml");
        var listOfItems = new List<Item>();
        foreach (XElement item in xdoc.Element("agricultural").Elements("file")) {
            listOfItems.Add(new Item() { Text = item.Element("text").Value, Value = item.Element("value").Value });
        }
            myDrp.DataTextField = "Text";
            myDrp.DataValueField = "Value";
            myDrp.DataSource = listOfItems;
            myDrp.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! Put the data binding code outside it. In fact, I wrote this code just now and in the NotePad ;-)

Comment: you know, and the class is not correct, this is a code that you can add ether in page_load, ether in a function. When you give some code give it correct because people tent to copy/paste it somewhere and as it is still not work.

Comment: I think people will understand that this is just an example. I didn't use any IDE such as Visual Studio for writing this code. You can edit that if you have any problem with it :-) The question is an ASP.NET question; so people know they should put this code in the Page_Load method.

Comment: the people that understand is the one they know the answer, but you are try to help the one that they do not know about. Because you know, do not take this as granted for the rest.